# What is the purpose of the "disabled" attribute?

Tags: html, css

This is not a technical question but rather a question about purpose.

I stumbled across the "disabled" attribute for options and I wondered about its purpose, why exactly is this attribute created? If you don't want this option to be available/selected, wouldn't it be better to just not show the option at all?

And can you guys give me a scenario where this attribute could be used?

PS: The "disabled" attribute in this scenario is to be used only for the "optgroup" or "option" tags and nothing else(e.g. Submit, input. etc.).

Comment: you can put a value in there that you want the user to see but dont want someone to edit, like an email address or something

Comment: From [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/): "*In contexts where user input is either undesirable or irrelevant, it is important to be able to disable a control or render it read-only. For example, one may want to disable a form's submit button until the user has entered some required data. Similarly, an author may want to include a piece of read-only text that must be submitted as a value along with the form.*" ([Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12))

Comment: You can disable a form input until some criteria is being placed, or for read-only values, for example. You can disable a submit form button that will only be enabled until some fields are inserted.

Comment: One use case with options are filter or search forms, that disable values that are no longer available in this combination. E.g. real estate where you might have a list of ZIP codes and equipment. Initially all values are available, but once you filter on a detail (e.g. swimming pool), some ZIP codes might no longer be available. As soon as you untick the equipment, the ZIP code is needed again.

Comment: @sthzg And that's the weird thing, shouldn't you just hide or make the options disappear since they are unneeded anyway?

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient If you hide them (or not) is up to you, but it is merely a visual representation. Your underlying data set (i.e. all real estate in our example) hasn't changed. It is easy to hide them visually, but if you deleted them from the DOM you would have to append them again, once the user changes her mind. I think of the visual representation and the underlying state as two separate aspects. ``disabled`` helps me to persist that state on the data layer, hiding it might (or might not) help the usability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to block the users from edditing the content of an input field, button,... but with javascript you can switch it between disabled and not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

READONLY and DISABLED both remove the functionality of the input field, but to different degrees. READONLY locks the field: the user cannot change the value. DISABLED does the same thing but takes it further: the user cannot use the field in any way, not to highlight the text for copying, not to select the checkbox, not to submit the form. In fact, a disabled field is not even sent if the form is submitted.

Source:htmlcodetutorial.com

Plus: To give an answer to the main question, this element can be activated again by the exchange of other form elements (with js). In addition, this process can be made for visual presentation.In addition Sometimes, in registration forms , users can choose field only one more time.

Comment: That's describing `<input>` elements, not `<option>`s. Also, use your own words, don't just copy someone else's.

Comment: The same/similar logic (in html). Plus:  Instead of criticizing me, you can help people.

Comment: No, it's actually quite different. Much of the text you've copied is not applicable to `<option>` elements: they cannot be set as `readonly`, as they are not editable, and disabling them does not affect what data is submitted with their parent form.